# Matrix and Conditional formatting in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating reports on Power BI and need one help on the below query. It's related to Matrix and conditional formatting. We want to display the arrows (downwards / upwards) as per selected columns and not as compare to previous columns. Its working fine when comparison is done with previous columns but when we select the the particular columns the arrows are not shown as expected.

In attached image the column C shows upward arrow because its higher as compare to column B but when we select column A and Column C it should have shown downward arrow.

[Image demonstrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxve3.png)

Much appreciated for all your help.
Thanks

I tried with table format , condtional formatting , Dax function for comparison, cumulative function, Bar graph